# Unable to read data as Llama index Documents

Tags: chatgpt-api, large-language-model, llama-index, gpt-4

I'm currently working with llama index trying to parse a column of my pandas dataframe as a Document object with llama index with the final goal of fitting my data into an LLM (I'm using gpt-4-32k). Does anyone know how to do this without explicitly converting to an unstructured datasource (ie. a doc) which seems counterintuitive?

```
    #First I save my data into an array (of strings)
text_list = concatenated_text_array = uniqueness_data['concatenated_text'].to_numpy().flatten()
#Then I try to cast each element to the Document object
documents = [Document(t) for t in text_list]


#and receive this error:
    documents = [Document(t) for t in text_list]
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 332, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Update:

documents = [Document(text = t) for t in text_list]